# Differences between MySQL DESCRIBE, SHOW COLUMNS FROM, SHOW CREATE TABLE and query to information_schema table

Tags: mysql-5.6

I have always checked table definitions through `DESCRIBE`, but today I came across something weird.

Another guy told me the `DEFAULT` value shown for a column through `SHOW CREATE TABLE` was different from what I got from `DESCRIBE`. I checked `information_schema` and I got the same result from `DESCRIBE`, so I’m curious why `SHOW CREATE TABLE` is showing something different.

Funny thing is some people at #mysql (IRC) told me this:

> protip: don’t use DESCRIBE or SHOW COLUMNS FROM, use information_schema

Funny enough, though I asked, no one told me the reason, and also given the one being different is `SHOW CREATE TABLE`, at this point I’m lost.

Given how the application works, I am trusting `SHOW CREATE TABLE`, but the wise people and my barely-knows-database knowledge tell me `information_schema` is right.

Could you please explain which option should I use, why, and when not, why does documentation mention nothing about not trusting one or the other?

Thanks in advance!